# 3.1 Surround Sound via optical out

Tags: sound-card, surround-sound, optical-cable

I have a Xonar DG sound card, and I'm outputting my computer sound via an optical cable. It's connected to a [3.1 Sony Sound Bar](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=6411250) (model ht-ct150).

Is there a setting/driver/software of some kind where I can output this as 3.1 surround sound so I can utilize the full capabilities of the sound bar? When I click on the Xonar Audio Center the only options it gives me are [here](http://ScrnSht.com/tahqcg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert on this, but when you look at this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolby_Digital#Channel_configurations

And be reminded, that usally, when you use your digital output, like optical out, then you don't configure a speaker configuration.

Because, I would say, that it's sufficient, when you put out a digital signal to your 3.1 speakers. They will decode it to the channels like they can.

So if you would place a 5.1 system behind your digital output, it would be 5.1 sound, if 3.1 it will be 3.1 sound.

All theses Audio-Channel configurations I know only to be useful, when you are using the seperate channel connectors on your soundcard or mainboard.

---

So basically, have you tried to setup VLC to use SPDIF and then looked if the sound was right?

Here is a setup example i found on the net - "use S/PDIF when available" is one part of the magic - the other is to select the SPDIF-Audio track and NOT the 5.1 one.

[image]

Or here is a nice vid setting up the Zoom-Player: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Anz5FX2VlaI